# how to push a file named by Chinese on avd

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

How to push a file named by Chinese on android virtual device ?
Here is a link to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKrCO.png),then the name of the file that I pushed will become gibberish,why and how to solve it ? Please help me ,thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: can you go to settings on the AVD device and set the language to Chinese

Comment: @user3535611 Thank you first,but I try to do it,then the problem  always exists.